# There is no proper subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb{Q}^+$ such that $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> There is no proper subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb{Q}^+$ such that $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$ is cyclic.

I have done the following:
(i) If $H$ is any proper subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}^+$ then $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$ is infinite.
(ii) Any two non-trivial subgroups of $\Bbb{Q}^+$ have non-trivial intersection.

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}^+$ such that $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$ is cyclic.
By (i), $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$ is infinite so it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^+$.
The hint given is the fact that $H\cap\Bbb{Z}^+\neq 0$ by (ii) but I can't see how it is related to $\Bbb{Q}^+/H$.

Comment: Note that ${\mathbb Q}^+$ is a divisible group i.e. for every $g \in G$ and positive integer $n$ there exists $h$ such that $nh=g$. Also quotients of divisible groups are divisible, but ${\mathbb Z}^+$  is not divisible.

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z^+$?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Additive group of integers

Comment: @AlanWang - Thanks! I was confused because I thought that ${\mathbb Q}^+$ was the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers, but now I see that the context shows that it is not so. (I would denote ${\mathbb Z}^+$ and ${\mathbb Q}^+$ by $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ respectively.)

Answer (score 1):

A try for a proof. Let $a$ be a representative of a generator of $\mathbb{Q}/H$. Then for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in H$ such that $x=na+r$. Now choose $x\not \in H$, and apply this for $x/k$, $k$ integer, $k\geq 1$. This imply that $x=kn_k a+s_k$, $s_k\in H$. Taking $k$ large wth respect to $|n_1|$, we see that $x(kn_k-n_1)\in H$ and $m=kn_k-n_1$ is non zero. Now apply the above with $k=m$: we get that $(mn_m-n_1)a\in H$, hence $n_1a\in H$, and $x\in H$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Derek Holt's argument in the comments seems to me to be the best one.

A group $G$ is said to be divisible if for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g\in G$ there exists $h\in G$ with $h^n= g$.

Clearly $(\Bbb{Q}, +)$ is divisible.

Moreover, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of the divisible group $G$, then $G/H$ is divisible: let $g+H \in G/H$, and let $n\in \Bbb{Z}$. Let $h\in G$ with $h^n = g$. Then $(h+H)^n = h^n + H = g+H$.

Therefore, here $\Bbb{Q}/H$ is divisible. But if it were cyclic, as you pointed out it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But $\Bbb{Z}$ is clearly not divisible, a contradiction.